# How do I change a network's name in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1

My network is named "Network 3" here:

[image]

and here:

[image]

I want it be something else. How do I change it?

**UPDATE**

Changing in not working in Windows-7 way.

Comment: I have provided two ways how to change via registry or by editing security policy. Please check my answer.

Comment: I'm going to use this question on any and all sales people trying to sell me a system with Windows 8... :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Change it via registry (Option 1)**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

You need to edit the `ProfileName` key.

**Change it via Local security policy (Option 2)**

- Start > run > `secpol.msc`
- In the left pane of Local Security Policy, click/tap on `Network List Manager Policies`
- In the right pane of Network List Manager Policies, double click/tap on your current network name.
- In Network Properties, select (dot) Name, type in a new name for the network you want, and click/tap on OK. (see screenshot below)
  NOTE: The default setting is Not configured. This will have the network name be what it is set as in OPTION TWO below..

Comment: Isn't that just like Microsoft? In Windows 7, you were able to rename them with a user interface. Generic home users didn't need that feature, so they removed the GUI option... and power users now have to browse through nasty-old registry to change that key - even though power users are used to it... because of things like this. :D

Comment: When you're running Windows 8.1 Basic, option 1 is the only option... :(

Comment: Idem 4 W10 Home

Comment: What actually sets these names? On WiFi, it always sets the name to the SSID, but for ethernet connections what determines the name of a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the network and sharing center, then click on the icon besides the work Network 3.

[image]

EDIT: It seemed logical this method would still work in Windows 8, but unfortunately it doesn't. The other solution is the one that will work.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Win8 anymore, but I can't check it.

Comment: In addition, if you are not allowed to change the name, open `Secpol.msc » network List manager Policies` and allow each network to change the name

Comment: Indeed, the icon to click on is gone...

Comment: Is not working in Windows 8

Comment: @Dims I just checked and indeed that icon is gone. Maybe if you configure the icon you can then change it that way, but given that in the same screen you can check the name, you should juse the secpol.msc solution given.

Comment: It's working for Windows 7, not for Windows 8.

Comment: @MOPTOH You must've missed my Edit then. I already stated there that it isn't working for windows 8.