# Network name, workgroup name, meaning and how to use it

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a home network with mainly windows devices.
Every device is member of the workgroup 'myworkgroup'

Also there is a network name, on my W10 pc, it's called 'network'.

What is the meaning of the network name? How do I use it sensible?
Are there more than one networks possible? Where else do I see this name?

And last: I use several WiFi network names for my wireless network.
Is there a connection between the wireless network and the wired pc's network name.

Answer (score 0):

*Network name* is profile name for the connection. It is possible to have more than one connection. Ex. additional network card. You can also change the name of the network in registry or `secpol.msc`.

There is no connection between `Wi-Fi SSID` and *Network name* of wired connection.

Comment: So I could name it things like 'internal' and 'internet', depending on my cards and their configuration?

Comment: Yes. http://superuser.com/a/741516/534726